# Tomee with spring managed cxf jaxrs rest services not working

Tags: spring, jax-rs, cxf, apache-tomee

I have an application that uses JAX-RS annotations and spring CDI.
It works fine in tomcat (apache-tomcat-7.0.57), but in Tomee-plus (apache-tomee-plus-1.7.2) it won't run with the error:

> Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.spring.NamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs]

In the tomcat version I include the cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs and cxf-rt-transports-http jars in the .war file, whereas for the Tomee-plus version I mark those jars as provided, as tomee-plus has those already.

This is my pom (just the dependencies cause that's about all there is (this is the tomee-plus version with scope=provided):

```
<properties>
<spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <cxf.version>2.6.16</cxf.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This is my spring config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
    xmlns:http-conf="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd
    ">
    <context:component-scan base-package="testrest" />

    <bean id="userService" class="testrest.UserService"/>

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml"/>
    <jaxrs:server id="restContainer" address="/">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="userService" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    </jaxrs:server>
</beans>
```

This is the web.xml

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>classpath:applicationConfig.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This is my REST service

```
@Component
@Path("/user")
public  class UserService {
    @GET
    @Path("get")
    public String get(){
        return "hello";
    }

}
```

When running in tomcat all works fine, but in tomee-plus I get the following exception (note that in tomee-plus the cxf jars are provided in the tomee lib dir and so are not included in the .war file)

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationConfig.xml]; nested exception is org.
springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.spring.NamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs]: problem with ha
ndler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/NamespaceHandlerSupport
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5528)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1095)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1930)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.spring.NamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs]:
problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/NamespaceHandlerSupport
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:140)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1422)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1417)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:174)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:144)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:100)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:510)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/NamespaceHandlerSupport
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1707)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.LazyStopWebappClassLoader.loadClass(LazyStopWebappClassLoader.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:249)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:125)
        ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

The root cause is reported as a class not found for org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport, but I think this is misleading. 
When tracing through the code I found that the error was caused by the class 'org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.spring.NamespaceHandler' not being able to be loaded because of a LinkageError.

The reason I need this is because I am trying to integrate a 3rd party lib that uses cfx and spring into an existing app.

Is this error related to class loading problems in tomee-plus, since cxf is in the tomee lib?

If I move the spring jars into the tomee-plus lib directory, it works fine, however, we want to avoid having to modify tomee at all.

Does anyone know how to get around this so that a spring/cfx app can be run in tomee-plus?

Comment: Hi Chris, it's been a while since you've posted your question. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: No Stiliyan, sorry. I avoided it by using vanilla tomcat, and now the client has pulled out so the app is no longer being used, so I didn't worry about it any more.

Answer (score 0):

The error :

> Invalid NamespaceHandler class
> [org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.spring.NamespaceHandler] for namespace
> [http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs]

Is due to the fact the artifact `cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs` is marked as provided in the pom:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
   <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
   <version>${cxf.version}</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Tomee provides cxf librairies but not all of them. CXF xml configuration namespace for Spring is in `cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs.jar` which is not provided by Tomee.

To solve this namespace issue you have to declare the dependency like this instead:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
   <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
   <version>${cxf.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

However, you might need to exclude some transitive dependencies that might be conflicting with classes provided by Tomee.